# How to avoid text overlapping?

Tags: html, css, laravel

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="bahagian" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label; responsive" style="position: relative; left: 105px; font-size:1w">BAHAGIAN :</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-10" id="kod_bahagian">
                        <select name="kod_bahagian"  class="form-control">    
                            <option value="">-- SEMUA --</option>
                        @foreach ($bahagians as $bahagian)
                        <option value="{{$bahagian->kod_bahagian}}">
                            {{ $bahagian->bahagian }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qil12/sqyhfLmx/1/

I need text left side and box in right side without overlapping.

Comment: Your text overlapping is caused by position:relative. Simply remove that and left:105px as well.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="kod_bahagian" class="col-sm-3">BAHAGIAN:</label> 
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select name="kod_bahagian"  class="form-control">  
                <option value="">-- SEMUA --</option>
                @foreach ($bahagians as $bahagian)
                    <option value="{{$bahagian->kod_bahagian}}">{{ $bahagian->bahagian }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `position:relative;left:105px;`. It moves the `<label>` **105px from left**, relative to its original position.

```css
#kod_bahagian{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="bahagian" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label; responsive" style="font-size:1w">BAHAGIAN :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="kod_bahagian">
        <select name="kod_bahagian"  class="form-control">    
            <option value="">-- SEMUA --</option>
        @foreach ($bahagians as $bahagian)
            <option value="{{$bahagian->kod_bahagian}}">
            {{ $bahagian->bahagian }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```